# Change data prop from JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new in Vue and I'm trying to change `this.data` using a `function`.

---

**App.vue:**

```
data () {
  return {
    data: null
  }
},
beforeMount: async function () {
  function something (response) {
    this.data = response
  }

  something('hello')

  console.log(this.data)
}
```

---

**Error:**

> Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: It's probably because `this` is being bounded when you define the function like that. try defining the function as `const something = (response) => {}` instead and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"this"` is lost in context.
read [This Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on mozilla

use arrow functions to preserve the scope of `this`, or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function

```
data () {
  return {
    data: null
  }
},
beforeMount: async function () {
  const something = (response) => {
    this.data = response
  }

  something('hello')

  console.log(this.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the methods section.

```
data () {
  return {
    data: null
  }
},
methods: {
 update(response) {
   this.data = response
 }
},
beforeMount: async function () {
  this.update('hello')

  console.log(this.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of 'this' not getting the bind context.
You can use either arrow function(Recommended ES6 way) or using bind(this) function

```
const something  = (response) => {
    this.data = response
  }
```